# How to retrieve with and height of an image tensor returned by tf.image.decode_jpeg?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to setup an images pipeline that builds an images dataset for Tensorflow that crops the images.
I followed this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/images) but I want to crop the file to a square and not resize it without preserving the aspect ratio. 
I can't figure out how to get their dimensions.

```
#
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
#

import glob


AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
IMAGE_SIZE = 192


def preprocess_image(path):
    img_raw = tf.io.read_file(path)
    img_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img_raw, channels=3)
    print("img_tensor")
    print(img_tensor)
    height = img_tensor.shape[0]
    print("height")
    print(height)
    return img_tensor


files_path = glob.glob('./images/*.jpeg')
image_count = len(files_path)
path_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files_path)
path_ds.map(preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

The tensor shape returned by `tf.image.decode_jpeg`  is :

```
Tensor("DecodeJpeg:0", shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=uint8)
```

How can I access the size of the jpg image ?

When I access it this way it works :

```
#
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
#

image = tf.io.read_file('./images/4c34476047bcbbfd10b1fd3342605659.jpeg/')
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)

print("image.shape")
print(image.shape)
```

It prints :

```
image.shape
(700, 498, 3)
```

Comment: it still shows (None,None,3) do you have any idea/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing this issue because the dataset is loaded lazily (only evaluated as it's needed).

Inherently, tf can only 'know' the size of the image if it either reads the file or we, as the developer, tell it. That may seem like an obvious point but it is worth bearing in mind.

So, given that a tf `Dataset` object can represent arbitrarily  large sequences of data (in fact, it's perfectly reasonable to represent infinite datasets this way), by design it doesn't read the files up front. Rather it reads them each time our downstream code needs a new example or batch.

I'm afraid it's really on us to either *know* the size of the images or to code against all possible sizes up front.

P.S. The reason you can get the second method to work is that it is eagerly evaluating the (single) tensor example.

P.P.S. You perhaps already know that you can "evaluate" the shape of any tensor at *execution* time with `tf.shape()` (and use the results of this in your dataset pre-processing pipeline) but you can't inspect it up front

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks ! Since I have a reasonably large data set,  I will do the processing outside of Tensorflow. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome - I should clarify though.... You can still do the pre-processing in tf. You just need to use the execution time operations (`tf.shape`) etc. The issue is trying to inspect the tensor's shape up front before it is "populated", no issue with using tensorflow for the preprocessing work

Comment: You'd just need to make sure that the dataset preprocessing operations accounted for all possible sizes of image (that's what I mean by 'coding against all possible sizes up front')

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by execution time operations ?

Comment: Thats a bit of an open ended question but in practical terms. `tf.shape(img_tensor)` will evaluate each time a new image is needed from your dataset whereas `img_tensor.shape` exists even before any data is read. Hence we can think of `img_tensor.shape` as a design-time property whereas `tf.shape(img_tensor)` is an operation only evaluated when the data is passed to it. A more commonplace example is having tensorflow operations with an unknown first dimension which represents a batch-size (only known at execution time)

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot. I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

We can do it. The key is to cast the return of `tf.shape()`, which appears to be `None` until the tensorflow graph is executed.

The following code resizes the images preserving the aspect ratio so that the height or width, whichever is shorter, is `256`, and then randomly crops it to be `224x224`.

```
def preprocess(filename, label):

    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(filename), channels=3)

    # Resize the image by converting the smaller edge to 256 
    shape = tf.shape(image)
    _h, _w = shape[0], shape[1] 
    _h, _w = tf.cast(_h, tf.float32), tf.cast(_w, tf.float32)
    ratio = tf.math.divide(tf.constant(256.), tf.math.minimum(_h, _w))
    ratio = tf.cast(ratio, tf.float32)

    image = tf.image.resize(
        image, tf.cast([_h*ratio, _w*ratio], tf.int32)
    )   

    image = tf.image.random_crop(image, [224,224,3])
    return image, label
```

I use this for ImageNet.